# RxJs | How to delay `mergeMap` to moment when previous inner observable completes?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, redux-observable

How to enqueue `mergeMap` operations so one by one get executed only when previous completes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of mergeMap you need to use concatMap.

Comment: But `concatMap` will emit only when all observables will complete, right? Is there's way to it emit every completed observable, and then start flattening next in queue?

Comment: no, it emits everything from the 1st stream, once it has been completed it switches to the next one and so on. While the mergeMap subscribes to everything and emits in parallel.

Comment: here you can see how it works (don't forget to open console) https://stackblitz.com/edit/concatmap-example